# Snapshot of screen shows toolbar on device but not on simulator

Tags: swift, webkit

I have a toolbar that's instantiated on viewDidLoad on top of a webkit. When I take a snapshot on the simulator, the toolbar is missing which is what I would like. When built on the device, the toolbar is there.

I tried to hide the toolbar with:

```
toolbar.isHidden = true
```

but the application crashes with toolbar being nil. If I change it to:

```
toolbar?.isHidden = true
```

It still shows up considering it still thinks it's nil.

The toolbar is set up on viewDidLoad by calling another function:

```
var toolbar : UIToolbar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpToolBar()
}

func setUpToolBar() {
        let saveButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(takeScreenshot))
... 
        let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 200, height: 50)) 
        toolbar.setItems([saveButton,flexibleSpaceFillerLeft,userAgentButton,flexibleSpaceFillerRight,doneButton], animated: true)

        view.addSubview(toolbar)
}
```

The code for my snapshot is below. This is where I tried to hide the toolbar before taking the snapshot.

```
   @objc func takeScreenshot() {

        webView.takeSnapshot(with: nil, completionHandler: { (image,error) in
            if let image = image {
                self.screenshotOfWindow = image
                self.showScreenshotEffect()
                self.saveAllData()
            } else {
                print (error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }
        })
    }
```

Here's the screen I need to take a screenshot of:

[image: screenshot]

The red box in the screenshot is the bar that I need to disappear from the screenshot.

I'd like to be able to take the screenshot without the bottom bar in view. As stated before, this works in the simulator, but the device always shows the bar. There's also a "navigation controller" gap at the top of the screenshot since the top bar covers part of the screen at top, but this is just blank and something I can address later.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to come back and answer how I solved this. The webview is embedded in a navigation controller, but I was creating the toolbar programmatically on viewDidLoad by calling a setupToolBar function I had created early on in the project. I could hide the toolbar, but it was still being captured while taking the screenshot. I commented all of that code out and used the navigation controller's toolbar instead. Now when I take the screenshot, the bottom and top bar of the navigation controller is not part of the screenshot.